# Laravel livewire route model binding validation limitation

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-livewire

Just trying to validate fields in a Livewire component using Route Model Binding feature.
When defining rules in specific function (required in docs for Route Model Binding to work), defining, e.g., a `unique` rule translates in a database error as the `post.message` field obviously does not exist:

```
...
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'post.message' => [
                           'required', 
                           'string', 
                           Rule::unique('posts')
                            ->where(function ($query) { return $query->where('user_id', Auth::id()); })
                            ->ignore($this->post->id)
                          ],
        ...
   ]
   ...
}
```

And the obvious error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'post.message' in 'where clause'
select
  count(*) as aggregate
from
  `posts`
where
  `post`.`message` = Hello
  and `id` <> 1
  and (`user_id` = 2)
```

Any ideas on how to implement it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what does your `posts` table look like? Clearly there's no "message" field on it.

Comment: There is a "message" field indeed. The problem lies in the array keys of the `rules()` method. For the `unique` rule to correctly work, those keys should be directly the field names, not preceeded by `post.`...

Comment: Ahh, I see. I overlooked the fact that it said `post` and not `posts` in the `WHERE` clause. Glad you resolved your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, I found the solution.
My fault, perhaps if I was looked better at the docs, I wouldn't have had this problem (like many other times I'm afraid).

As stated in the docs, the `unique` rule of the `Rule` object lets specifying the specific column of the database to search in through a second parameter, so the solution was to simply add that parameter to the rule:

`Rule::unique('posts', 'message')->where(function ($query)...`

Thanks again.